# Trim a Japani Text which is not trimming

Tags: php

I have a Japani text like below

```
$str = "ラブライブ！スクールアイドルフェスティバルall_stars（スクスタ）";
```

I am trying to remove the last space from this sentence. I have tried below ways.

```
echo trim($str);  // still getting space
```

Also tried

```
echo preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',$str)
```

Still getting the space. How can I remove this last space from this sentence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last character of the string

```
$str = "ラブライブ！スクールアイドルフェスティバルall_stars（スクスタ）";
```

is not a space. It is a [Unicode Character 'FULLWIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS' (U+FF09)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff09/index.htm). What we see as a round bracket and a blank is actually a single Unicode character. This character must be replaced by a normal round closing bracket.

```
$trimString = preg_replace("~）$~u", ')', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
First :
' '= '_'

```
echo preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','_',$str);
```

Second :
Trim()

```
echo trim(preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',$str));
```

Comment: I am getting the same output.

Comment: Try first one to get like eg : $str="name var"; output like name_var